# How to consume a SOAP WebService over HTTPS in Grails

Tags: java, web-services, grails, soap, groovy

How to consume a webservice over https in Grails,Groovy or Java. I have the following code which connects in PHP. I have the wsdl and .pem file.

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    "http://localhost:8081/axis2/services/SomeWebService?wsdl", 
    array(
        "local_cert" => "C:\ws\MyProject\php\cert.pem",
        "trace" => 1));
```

Is there a way in Java to specify .pem file in SOAP Client?